# Why are means not relevant to binary variables?

Tags: mean, binary-data

Trying to learn Basic Statistics from the Coursera.

At the time 29 second, the [video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-statistics/lecture/MT1DD/5-06-sampling-distribution-proportion) says:
Means are not relevant with such a binary variable.

Why?

Comment: It is better to be positive than negative. Does anyone really suppose that the mean of male and female is hermaphrodite? Rather, explain that a coding of 0 for male and 1 for female means that the mean over data is the fraction female. (Feel free to change the example.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example of the video, people are classified as "Hipster" or "Non-Hipster". That is a nominal scale level. Nominal data can be counted but not added. Without addition, there is no computing means. The mean of a "Hipster" and a "Non-Hipster" is not "Non-Hipster and a half".

You can count people and compute means of counts but not means of people. Saying that "a proportion of 0.10 of all students are hipsters" is a computation based on the counts of hipsters, not computation on the hipsters themselves. That is what makes this introduction so counter-intuitive.

Comment: yep, there can't be a mean which describes a person who is 0.75 Hipster. thanks.

Comment: Whilst true I am not shure that a .75 Hipster will direct your thoughts to the central point. Imagine people could be either "hipster" or "punk" or "none". Give each of these three possibilities a number to encode it. Then it will be obvious that doing any computation such as computing means does not make any sense anymore. A punk is not something in between none and a hipster, nor are two hipsters in any sensible way equal to two punks.

Comment: True. I guess I was confused because that I was thinking of the mean of the counts of Hipsters and Non-Hipsters with the mean of .... I don't know what to call it....